# New to Java, trying to use Date as attribute

Tags: java, date, constructor, arguments

I'm completely new to Java and i'm trying to create a simple class named Message to print simple text messages.

When I try to use the class in my main code, it always errors when I include the date. When I leave the date out of my constructor it works fine.

What i've got so far:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Message {

    private String sender;
    private Date curdate;
    private String message;

    // constructor when empty
    public Message() {
        sender = "unknown";
        curdate = curdate;
        message = "unknown";

    }

    // constructor with 3 values
    public Message(String s, Date d, String m) {
        sender = s;
        curdate = d;
        message = m;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String s) {
        this.sender = s;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return curdate;
    }

    public void setDate(Date d) {
        this.curdate = d;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String m) {
        this.message = m;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sender + " " + curdate + " " + message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your `main` method code?

Comment: the constructor looks strange in one line:   curdate = curdate; .. Needs to assigned to null. Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I suggest a little more study. Like the free-of-cost [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle. And the [Head First Java](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009205.do) book from O'Reilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your empty constructor is wrong

```
public Message() {
    sender = "unknown";
    // curdate = curdate; /* curdate = {undefined} */
    curdate = new Date();
    message = "unknown";
}
```

Comment: I understand my question was a bit vague, but this did the trick. Thanks! Just have to find out what format i need to use when using it in my main as attribute. (for example `Message testmessage = new Message("Bob", 19-01-2014, "Test");` doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

you should understand difference between java object and referrence.

private Date curdate;  #this is just a java referrence

you did not assign any Date object to curdate reference.

> please assign curdate=new Date()